# How I can work with SVG files in Qt creator?

Tags: c++, svg, qt-creator

I have some problem. I need to read SVG files and place content on the QGraphicsView scene. I read documentation about QSvgWidget and QSvgRenderer, but don't understand how get all shapes from file, point coordinates, where place they and have a posibillity to change color, size and other properties. Who can suggest methods, how I can do this? Thanks in advance!

I tried create QSvgWidget and I managed draw one figure with his color, but if figures more than one, they all dye in black color, and I don't know, how I can control this.

```
ui->setupUi(this);
scene = new QGraphicsScene;
scene->setSceneRect(-200, -100, 400, 200);
svg_widget = new QSvgWidget(":/resources/Test3.svg");
svg_widget->renderer();
svg_rend = new QSvgRenderer;
painter = new QPainter;
svg_rend->render(painter);
svg_widget->render(painter);
scene->addWidget(svg_widget);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

I understood that after creating QSvgWidget and call renderer(), QSvgRenderer does not affect on work with SVG. Can I combine svg_rend with svg_widget? Or does it make no sense?

Comment: It is unknown what you did. Can you post code? You tried to render each element separately but got only one colored others black?

Comment: @ÖöTiib I edit my question, provide a code snippet

Comment: What is the purpose of the code between `new QSvgWidget` and `scene->addWidget(svg_widget)`?

Comment: @Osyotr at first I thought, that it affect on the drawing of picture. Later I tried to comment this section of code, understood, that it not important. Properly I want to find out, why do I need `QSvgRenderer`, or it is excess? How I can read SVG file, set some properties and display picture in `QGraphicsView`?